# Magento 2 : Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 588

Tags: magento2, php, admin, magento2.3.2, encryption-key

I am facing this error after a move to new server Magento customer login

```
{"0":"Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /www/web/demo/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 588"
```

PHP Version is the same: PHP Version 7.2.24-he.0

Sodium from Frank Denis

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks In advance..!

Comment: Have you faced this error when you log in to admin panel?

Comment: No, admin login worked without problems.

Comment: @SanjayGohil, yes, I faced this issue while admin login, I created a new admin too but that did not help

Answer (score 2):

We are facing the same issue.

For me, it got solved after installing PHP version 7.2 and installing the php7.2-sodium extension

Try this solution and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Prince Kumar it's work for me

Comment: Welcome sagar. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if you have the sodium ext in your PHP using the command below.

```
php -i | grep -i libsodium
```

I had the same issue accessing the admin panel even with the Sodium extension installed, I solved it recreating the admin user using [Magerun](https://magerun.net):

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && alias magerun="./n98-magerun2.phar"

magerun admin:user:delete admin

magerun admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="pa55w0rd123" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Comment: did not work for me :(

Comment: 'Command "admin:user:delete" is not defined'

Comment: It's fixed @00-BBB , I added the command to download Magerun to run it!